# CSS - How to pin footer to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I am working on a small personal project to try and relearn HTML & CSS and I am having some issues with pinning the footer of my site to the bottom of the page.The site can be found [here](http://rdoyle.info/temp/v4/).

I have tried searching online and found that my footer CSS should have the following:

```
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
```

This does pin it to the bottom but it exceeds the width of my container and doesn't look right. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand how position: fixed; is working. It ignores any surrounding element. ie. A fixed position element is positioned relative to the view-port, or the browser window itself.

Your `.container` styles are:

```
margin: auto;
width: 75%;
```

So apply this also to the footer:

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 75%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px;
    background: #2D2D2D;
    border-top: 12px solid #3E3E3E;
}
```

Comment: I have added the code you suggested but now I have lost the ability to scroll the content in my main row div. I want the footer the scroll down the page dynamically as the content grows within the main row (content) div.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to play around with the width of the footer to see what fits. e.g.

```
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
body {
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%; 
}

footer {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

footer:before, footer:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; 
}

footer:after {
  clear: both; 
}
```